# How to solve SlickGrid bug in dataview example "getEditor(columnDef) is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

In Firefox I am getting a javascript bug on one of the best SlickGrid examples
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

It happens after the 2nd click, and here is the report from Firebug:
Any tips?

```
getEditor(columnDef) is not a constructor
makeActiveCellEditable(editor=-12)slick.grid.js (line 1883)
editor = -12
[Break On This Error] cancelChanges: cancelEditAndSetFocus
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/slickgrid/browse_thread/thread/a69628d87ada88d